# Next js css loading only at home page

Tags: next.js

Next Js css is loading only at home page not in other page if I go the url directly .

when I go to homepage css loads
https://www.kachuwa.com
It also load if it push through router:

```
 router.push({
      pathname: '/shop/nosidebar/list',
      query: {
        searchTerm: 'shoes',
      },
    });
```

but going to url directly it won't load the css:
https://www.kachuwa.com/shop/nosidebar/list/?searchTerm=shoes
what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Create ***_app.js*** on your root folder
Import your CSS inside ***_app.js*** like this

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
```

Copy this code into ***_app.js***

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp;
```

Check these links below to understand better:
[what is _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)
[How to use css on _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)